# Removing question separators in survey

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, web-part, survey, style.css

I am creating a survey in sharepoint. I've already customized quite a bit and am now trying to divide my questions into sections.

As such I would like to be able to take off the line separators for certain questions (if it is too complicated or not possible, I am willing to take them off for all questions).

Basically instead of having:

---

question 1

---

question 2

---

question 3

---

I would have (e.g. here my new section starts at question 3):

question 1

question 2

---

question 3

Would anyone know what CSS code I can add to make this possible? I haven't been able to find an answer.

Thanks a lot!

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

That should do the trick

```
.ms-formtable > tbody > tr:nth-child(x) > .ms-formbody {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

- If you want to have a line below the 1st question then replace **x** with **2**.
- If you want to have a line below the 2nd question then replace
  **x** with **4**
- And so on..